# Replacement for DirectoryIndexRedirect for older versions of Apache

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects

`DirectoryIndexRedirect` is available in version 2.3.14 and later. ([mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html))

Is there an alternative method for older versions? I have different `DirectoryIndex` directive sets for a lot of directories and would like a generic rule I can apply on the root directory. That way I would not have to maintain separate redirect rules for each directory.

Comment: I guess you already have separate .htaccess files for each subdirectory, rather than one common one in the root?

Comment: I have one in the root with alle the `<Directory>`s.

Comment: In that case, have you considered using mod_rewrite/`RewriteRule` instead of `DirectoryIndex`, although you seem to suggest that this would be more trouble?